# Do questions about YARA rules syntax belong here?

Tags: discussion

A few weeks ago I had a question related to YARA rules syntax where YARA was used in `VirusTotal`. I asked it here first, because YARA is a tool made firstly for security researchers, and got no replies.

I then deleted my question and asked it on `StackOverflow`. Using the search function, it looks like more YARA questions are in `StackOverflow` than here but, as said earlier, it is quite a specific tool directed at people who work with security.

A rough example of such case could be:

> "Why does my rule `testRule` match a file that does not have a string
>   `$a1` when I specify it in the condition?"

So a question of such nature should be asked here or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

No. Questions about syntax belong on sites closer to the relevant technology. Just because the file is used in a security tool does not make it a security question.

Think in terms of the OSI model. Syntax is a file/parser layer. Security is a few layers above that.